# Death of Nadav & Avihu/ Human Sacrifice?

Tags: rashi, pentateuch-chumash

According to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.10.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Leviticus.10.3.1&lang2=bi) the death of Nadav and Avihu was (as earlier to to Moshe by G-D) in order to sanctify the Mishkan. So in a sense the sanctification of the Mishkan (i.e. G-D's indwelling within it) required human sacrifice.

Is there a a reason for this human sacrifice given? Or a precedent of human sacrifice for a holiness to manifest?

(Note: this is just according to Rashi.)

Comment: I'm not sure it was "in order to sanctify the Mishkan", and I don't think the Mishkan "required human sacrifice". Can you clarify where you see Rashi saying this?

Comment: @robev Vayikra 10:3, quoting the medrash but I don't think that it means what the question presumes it means.

Comment: What else could the words כדי שיתקדש הבית (in order that the house become sanctified) mean?