# Human sacrifice / collective penalty / penalty on somebody else's behalf

Tags: halacha, korban

I came onto [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/what-does-islam-exclusively-say-about-human-sacrifice) on Islam.SE, citing a variety of situations where humans were sacrificed, not for a personal guilt on which death penalty has been decreed.

[Numbers 31:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.31.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): Ritual slaughter of the enemies?

[Deuteronomy 13:13-19](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.13.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): Collective killing for avoda zara, to please God?

([Joshua 7:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.7.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)): Death penalty by lot.

([Judges 11:29-40](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.11.29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)): Human sacrifice to fulfil a wow.

([1 Kings 13:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.13?lang=bi)): Human sacrifice on the Altar in Bethel.

In a completely different [answer, Michael](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/119447/24085) states that Judaism rejects human sacrifice. Of course, human sacrifice is no more practised, but how are those past events received in later Judaism? Has there been a concrete prophecy in later times that stopped this?

Related Question (so far without an answer):
[Death of Nadav & Avihu/ Human Sacrifice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121642/death-of-nadav-avihu-human-sacrifice)

Comment: I gave a downvote because the question seems to me to be working from a bias, trying to show something that isn't there. These are disparate actions each with a very weak connection to the notion you are trying to show, certainly there was never a time where Jews were commanded to kill and offer a human as an altar sacrifice to God. A commandment to kill is not the same thing as a sacrifice.

Comment: I am fully aware that this is a question that may seem hostile. It is in fact not me who raised it but someone who asked me on the Islam site claimed this, and I didn't feel authorised to answer on behalf of the Jewish community, and felt like lacking knowledge. Please look up the link to see the background. It was not my intention to insult you.

Comment: The question has been closed for lacking clarity. What needs to be clarified? I was looking out for good arguments. The single answer is already good, but why should others not contribute?

Comment: @BID Unfortunately, this question was closed. Maybe you can file your answer on the original question linked on Islam Stack Exchange if you don't fear the downvotes because it is not the answer on Islam ..

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. I hope you enjoy yourself on Mi Yodeya!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer briefly:

*Numbers 31:7: Ritual slaughter of the enemies?*

It was a war of retribution  against enemies. Not a  ritual slaughter of them. Even against  the enemies themselves there were limitations. Rashi says they were only told to fight against Midyan but not Moav despite Moav's involvement in that story because Moav was motivated by (incorrect) fear of invasion.

*Deuteronomy 13:13-19: Collective killing for avoda zara, to please God?*

The Tosefta (Sanhedrin 14:1) says that such a case never happened and never will.

*(Joshua 7:15): Death penalty by lot.*

More accurately: A prophet was able to  determine guilt through a lot for a crime that carried the death penalty

*(Judges 11:29-40): Human sacrifice to fulfil a wow.*

No one was actually physically  sacrificed in that story  At the time the vow was made he didn't think it would be a human who the vow would end up referring to. And he was criticized in the Gemora for not having the vow annulled

*(1 Kings 13:1-2): Human sacrifice on the Altar in Bethel.*

That was a prophetic warning to an evil king (Yerevom Ben Novot) about his end. Being that Yerovom was king he didn't say directly. It is not a commandment or the way things are done.